# How to select specific images and save from a particular url? (Description Inside)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I need to select and save some specific images from a site by entering the url in the textbox in my site.

I've loaded all the images from a site url, by using html agility. but now I don't know how to select and save.

For example, I enter http://flipkart.com/ in my text box, it should load all images from that page, assume it contains 9 images, if 9 images loaded from a site and displayed as a gallery, from that gallery I will select 1 image click save. it should save somewhere in my site(may be a particular folder).

I don't know how to save images from a site.

would somebody give some reference or ideas to achieve this task of saving the image that is loaded when a url is given.

Thanks!

Comment: Images on this site seems to be created by dynamic javascript. If you do a view source on it, you will only see a few images in the raw HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled about this and got the below code,

```
public System.Drawing.Image DownloadImageFromUrl(string imageUrl)
{
    System.Drawing.Image image = null;

    try
    {
        System.Net.HttpWebRequest webRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(imageUrl);
        webRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
        webRequest.Timeout = 30000;
        System.Net.WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
        System.IO.Stream stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
        image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
        webResponse.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return image;
}
```

u use this code and save this as an image of desired format.

while saving the image you should mention the Folder/destination path.

Answer (score 2):

```
string imageUri = "http://www.contoso.com/library/homepage/images/";
            string fileName = "ms-banner.gif", myStringWebResource = null;
            // Create a new WebClient instance.
            WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
            // Concatenate the domain with the Web resource filename.
            myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName;
            Console.WriteLine("Downloading File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\" .......\n\n", fileName, myStringWebResource);
            // Download the Web resource and save it into the current filesystem folder.
            myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource,fileName);     
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully Downloaded File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\"", fileName, myStringWebResource);
```

In myStringWebResource you will mention the path to you folder. I assume you are doing it from the same website on which you want to save the image

**EDIT:**
*I've seen that, but can we use a webclient to load all images from a site. for example if I gave flipkart.com, will it display all images in that page. – Gopinath Perumal*

- First you need to get the html as string from web client
- Then you need to find all the uri in th string which ends with .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .gif etc etc
- Iterate the webclient and download each image

But beware, programatically crawling like this is not permitted by many site.

Comment: I've seen that, but can we use a webclient to load all images from a site. for example if I gave http://flipkart.com, will it display all images in that page.

Comment: I've already done upto, if we enter a url it will show you the list of images from that site.

Comment: @Mayur Urls don't have to end with `.jpg, .jpeg, .png, .gif` etc. <img> tag is the keyword here.

Comment: @GopinathPerumal so if you have all the url then iterate the web client and download the image by download file method